# Pandas iterate over rows and find the column names

Tags: python, pandas, loops

i have a two dataframes as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'America':["Ohio","Utah","New York"],
                   'Italy':["Rome","Milan","Venice"],
                   'Germany':["Berlin","Munich","Jena"]});


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cities':["Rome", "New York", "Munich"],
                   'Country':["na","na","na"]})
```

i want to itirate on df2 "Cities" column to find the cities on my (df) and append the country of the city (df column names) to the df2 country column

Comment: did it. thanx for the answer and notice

Comment: Thank you for upvote, but for accepting is necessary click to empty tick next `9`, check link in above comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary:

```
df1 = df.melt()
print (df1)
  variable     value
0  America      Ohio
1  America      Utah
2  America  New York
3    Italy      Rome
4    Italy     Milan
5    Italy    Venice
6  Germany    Berlin
7  Germany    Munich
8  Germany      Jena

df2['Country'] = df2['Cities'].map(dict(zip(df1['value'], df1['variable'])))
#alternative, thanks @Sandeep Kadapa 
#df2['Country'] = df2['Cities'].map(df1.set_index('value')['variable'])
print (df2)
     Cities  Country
0      Rome    Italy
1  New York  America
2    Munich  Germany
```

Comment: Or `df2['Cities'].map(df1.set_index('value')['variable'])`

Answer (score 1):

After melting and renaming the first dataframe:

```
df1 = df.melt().rename(columns={'variable': 'Country', 'value': 'Cities'})
```

the solution is a simple merge:

```
df2 = df2[['Cities']].merge(df1, on='Cities')
```